# Remove newlines inside <p> blocks

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
<p>Here some text
another line</p>

<p>Another paragraph
another line</p>
```

What I want is something like following :

```
<p>Here some text another line</p>

<p>Another paragraph another line</p>
```

Basically I want to remove new line character from the string within paragraph tags not anywhere else.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [The pony he comes....](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/554546)

Comment: What is the reason for doing so?

Comment: @FelixKling The reason for this is that I want to remove paragraph tags from the string and need to use it somewhere else. So former code in a html page will not show the line break inside paragraph tag. but it will be shown in a textarea. But I want to show this string as it's shown on html page in textarea without the paragraph tags. Hope you are getting me.

Comment: Have you looked into [Tidy](http://php.net/tidy)?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use preg_replace.

```
$string = "<p>Here some text
another line</p>

<p>Another paragraph
another line</p>


<p>test



123</p>
blah";
$pattern = '/<p>([^\n]+)\n+([^\n]+)/iS';
$replacement = "<p>$1 $2";

$paragraphs = explode("</p>",$string);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($paragraphs); $i++) {
    $paragraphs[$i] = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $paragraphs[$i]);
}

$string = implode("</p>", $paragraphs);

echo $string . "\n";
```

Comment: If you also want to condense the whitespace characters as well change the `\n+` to `\s+`

Answer (score 1):

`devNoise`, your code works great unless there are multiple lines `\n`.  I'm sure there's a better way to do this with regexp than what I'm posting here, but here it is:

```
    $string = "<p>Here some text
    another line</p>

    <p>Another paragraph
    another line</p>


    <p>test



    123</p>";

    $paragraphs = explode("</p>",$string);

    for ($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++) {
            if (strstr($string[$i].$string[$i+1].$string[$i+2],"<p>")) {
                    $replace_on = 1;
            }

            if (strstr($string[$i].$string[$i+1].$string[$i+2].$string[$i+3],"</p>")) {
                    $replace_on = 0;
            }

            if ($replace_on==1) {
                    if (strstr($string[$i],"\n")) {
                            $new_string .= " ";
                    } else {
                            $new_string .= $string[$i];
                    }
            } else {
                    $new_string .= $string[$i];
            }
    }

    echo $new_string;
```

Comment: I have revised my answer to handle multiple new lines based on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

**If text only contains paragraphs**

```
$string = "<p>Here some text
another line</p>

<p>Another paragraph
another line</p>";

$output = '';

$paragraphs = array_filter(explode("</p>", $string));

foreach ($paragraphs as $block) {
    $output .= str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $block);       
}

var_dump($output); //<p>Here some textanother line</p><p>Another paragraphanother line</p>
```

**If text contains multiple tags**

```
$string = "<p>Here some text 

another line</p>

<img src=\"/path/to/file.jpg\";

<div id=\"test\"> 
   <p>Another paragraph 



another line</p>
</div>";

preg_match_all('~<p>(.+?)</p>~si', $string, $paragraphs);

foreach ($paragraphs[0] as $block) {
    $output = '';

    if (strlen($block)) {
        $output = str_replace(array("\r","\n"), '', $block);
        $string = str_replace($block, $output, $string);
    }
}
```